# How to make certain column in primefaces datatable to be dragable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need dragable feature to be applied on certain columns of the datatable. As of now when we use dragable datatable its applied to all columns. Can anyone have any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: A draggable column moved past a fixed column will make it shift position. What do you want to to do exactly?

Comment: As a example If I have 5 columns in the datatable I need only 3 of them are draggable

Comment: Check if "Frozen Columns" can help you. See [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml).

Comment: or check the client-side js to see if by e.g. adding a custom class you can prevent the dragging of certain columns